# How to set Expand and Collapse state in ios swift for VoiceOver?

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility

I'm trying to find out how to set the Expand and Collapse state for the VoiceOver screen reader, but I can't find it in any documentation or forums.

On Android it's [AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_EXPAND](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo#ACTION_EXPAND:kotlin.Int) or [AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_COLLAPSE](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo#ACTION_COLLAPSE:kotlin.Int). I would like to find the equivalent for **SWIFT IOS**. Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`UIAccessibilityTraits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility/uiaccessibilitytraits) is how states are indicated. It's part of [`UIAccessibility`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibility) and not part of Swift, but you can set UIAccessibilityTraits from Swift.  However, iOS does not have a natively supported expand/collapse property, unlike Android.  You'll have to code around it by using [`accessibilityHint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615093-accessibilityhint).

Comment: Thank you so much!
I opened an issue in flutter asking to add an attribute in Semantics to set Expanded and Collapsed states. I'll send your answer there, okay? If you want to follow up, the issue link is https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92040

Comment: I thought you were looking for a Swift answer, not Flutter, but either is ok.  I'm not sure how these programming languages handle surfacing a feature that is native on one mobile platform but not another.  Perhaps with a polyfill of sorts.

Comment: Yes, my question was for Native IOS.

About the framework, React Native has this accessibility feature, but Flutter doesn't have this feature.

I'm trying to implement this feature directly in Flutter :)